# Applying conditional in Django CharFields interaction

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In my Django's **model.py** I have the following entry:

```
class Method1(models.Model):
    clustering_method_param     = models.CharField(max_length=20,
         default='ward', blank=True, choices=(
         ('complete', 'Complete linkage'),
         ('average','Average linkage'),
         ('ward','Ward'),))

    distance_method_param     = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,
            default='euclidean', choices=(
           ('euclidean', 'Euclidean'),
          ('manhattan','Manhattan'),
          ('pearsond','Pearson Correlation'),))
```

Which later rendered as this in HTML:

[image]

What I want to do is to set the condition. Namely the clustering method `ward` can only be applied with distance measure `euclidean`. If the user pass all other distance measure to `ward` it should return error message. How can I apply that in Django? Or should I use JavaScript instead?

Here is the example of the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://gregpike.net/demos/bootstrap-file-input/bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>


<body>
   <form  id="id-method1Form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" > <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='vr5MftcSxGGUeIOwKioeUlalXJdXNgkl' /> <div id="div_id_clustering_method_param" class="form-group"> <label for="id_clustering_method_param" class="control-label col-lg-2">
                Clustering method
            </label> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <select class="select form-control" id="id_clustering_method_param" name="clustering_method_param">

<option value="complete">Complete linkage</option>
<option value="average">Average linkage</option>
<option value="ward" selected="selected">Ward</option>
</select> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_distance_method_param" class="form-group"> <label for="id_distance_method_param" class="control-label col-lg-2">
                Distance measure
            </label> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <select class="select form-control" id="id_distance_method_param" name="distance_method_param">
   
<option value="euclidean" selected="selected">Euclidean</option>
<option value="manhattan">Manhattan</option>
<option value="pearsond">Pearson Correlation</option>
</select> </div> </div>  <div class="form-group"> <div class="aab controls col-lg-2"></div> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <input type="submit"
    name="submit"
    value="Submit"
    
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="submit-id-submit"
    
    
    /> </div> </div> </form>

    <!--- END FORM DISPLAY-->
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 'User Experience', i think you will need to write a javascript to change all distance according the clustering_method_param selected.

But, if you just want to 'block' this on django.
You can write a form validation, like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    clustering_method_param = cleaned_data.get('clustering_method_param', None)
    distance_method_param = cleaned_data.get('distance_method_param', None)

    if clustering_method_param == 'ward':
        if distance_method_param != 'euclidean':
            self.errors.update(
                {
                    'distance_method_param': [u'It should be euclidean.']
                }
            )
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot see any effect of it. I updated my Django. I use `class Method1(models.Model):` And if we'd like to go JavaScript way how can I do it?

Comment: you need add this clean into the Form Class.

Comment: this tutorial, can help you with the ajax.
https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/a-simple-django-example-with-ajax/

Comment: You mean put clean() in **forms.py** ?

Comment: It works!! After I put in forms.py but  inthe message display the letters vertically!!!! how can correct that?

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript and Ajax is a proven fix for your problem. You can listen to the user selection on first drop-down and then display the second drop-down accordingly based on the response via ajax.

Comment: can you give example of the JavaScript? I've uploaded the HTML code.